# What is the etiquette for extending my question?

Tags: discussion, comments, edits, questions, etiquette

I've recently asked a question, then thought about it more, and now I want to add to my question something like "I've tried A and it didn't work. Might B work?"

What is the etiquette for this kind of thing?

Should I comment, or edit the post?

Do I need to make clear I've edited the post, or just treat the edited post as if it was always like that?

Comment: Did you already receive answers? If yes, make sure your edit doesn't invalidate those answers. If no, just make the edit. Do not add meta noise like "EDITED"or "New Info!" to your question. Edit in the new bits in the natural flow of the question\

Comment: See also some of these questions: https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=editing+existing+question+is%3Aq+hasaccepted%3Ayes if you have a specific edge case you want covered.

Comment: That's helpful, ta!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the recommended guidance when [no one answers your question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers):

> Edit your question to provide status and progress updates. Document your own continued efforts to answer your question. This will naturally bump your question to the homepage and get more people interested in it.

You generally don't need to indicate the edit with something like **EDIT:**, it's clear from the revision history that it's an edit.

Comments are [temporary notes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); the information you want to add is of a more permanent nature, so an edit is more appropriate.

Comment: I think it would be better to say “Do not indicate” or “Please don’t indicate” rather than “You generally don’t need to indicate”.